# How do you create a server client application in python where the client doesn't need to port forward?

Tags: python, sockets, portforwarding

I see that desktop apps like discord or chrome can talk to their servers without me having to port forward anything, the server can send them information and they send information back, how is this done? I have been searching for about 2 hours but I am very new to this and don't know any of the proper search terms.

Comment: The basic technique is pretty simple -- have the client connect to the server via TCP.  Since the server is not firewalled (or if it is, it is set up to let connections through on the port the server is listening on), this works without requiring port forwarding on the client.  Once the TCP connection is established, data can flow across it in either direction.